# Unable to start Mongod properly on CentOS7

Tags: mongodb, centos7

After run `mongod --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb --repair`, I had the following errors and now I cannot boot my MongoDB by 'service mongod start', can anybody help me? More than one day had been used to solve this problem, but it did not help!

```
{
    "t": { "$date": "2022-03-30T15:41:52.386+08:00" },
    "s": "E",
    "c": "STORAGE",
    "id": 22435,
    "ctx": "initandlisten",
    "msg": "WiredTiger error",
    "attr": {
        "error": 24,
        "message": "[1648626112:360534][222937:0x7f65fb141bc0], file:collection-76-7324578283188304824.wt, WT_SESSION.open_cursor: __posix_open_file, 808: /home/mongodb/data/collection-76-7324578283188304824.wt: handle-open: open: Too many open files"
    }
} 
{
    "t": { "$date": "2022-03-30T15:41:52.402+08:00" },
    "s": "F",
    "c": "STORAGE",
    "id": 50882,
    "ctx": "initandlisten",
    "msg": "Failed to open WiredTiger cursor. This may be due to data corruption",
    "attr": {
        "uri": "table:collection-76-7324578283188304824",
        "config": "",
        "error": {
            "code": 264,
            "codeName": "TooManyFilesOpen",
            "errmsg": "24: Too many open files"
        },
        "message": "Please read the documentation for starting MongoDB with --repair here: http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/repair"
    }
} 
{
    "t": { "$date": "2022-03-30T15:41:52.402+08:00" },
    "s": "F",
    "c": "-",
    "id": 23091,
    "ctx": "initandlisten",
    "msg": "Fatal assertion",
    "attr": {
        "msgid": 50882,
        "file": "src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_session_cache.cpp",
        "line": 109
    }
} 
{
    "t": { "$date": "2022-03-30T15:41:52.405+08:00" },
    "s": "F",
    "c": "-",
    "id": 23092,
    "ctx": "initandlisten",
    "msg": "\n\n***aborting after fassert() failure\n\n"
}
```

I first run `rm -r mongod.lock` & `rm -r storage.bson` in db folder,  and then `mongod --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb --repair`, but they did not help.

Comment: the initial error message suggest something like: "Too many open files"   , do you have enought open files?  maybe you need to increase ulimit ...

Comment: Thanks! I have solved this problem yesterday. I just deleted mongod.lock&_repair_incomplete in the data folder, and then run `mongod -config mongo.conf --fork`.